# Resolve 'Conflicting definitions for node' TS4090 error in VS 2017

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, aurelia

I have a TypeScript project that builds and runs, but I have a ton of build errors that all seem to stem from one error:

> TS4090: (TS) Conflicting definitions for 'node' found at 'C:/[projectpath]/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts' and 'C:/[user path to Microsoft]/Typescript/3.1/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts'.  Consider installing a specific version of this library to resolve the conflict.

I don't understand the bit about "installing a specific version of this library".  I'm not certain why two versions are being found to begin with.

My app has a `tsconfig.json` file located in the `ClientApp` folder.  It contains the following:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
        "es2016",
        "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
    "atom": {
        "rewriteTsconfig": false
    },
    "typeAcquisition": {"enable": false}
}
```

I added the `typeAcquisition` recently based on comments on other posts relating to this -- but it had no affect.

What do I need to do to "install a specific version of this library"?

**Environment**

The project targets .NetCore 2.2.  The project contains WebAPI Controllers that serve up backend data as well as a ClientApp folder that contains a SPA UI created with Aurelia.  I use WebPack to build the SPA application.

**Errors**

[image]

Comment: try deleting the node_modules folder _and_ deleting your `package-lock.json` file inside your project and removing `@types/node` from `package.json`. Re-install . your node-modules with `npm i` and re-install your node types as a dev dependency with `npm i @types/node --save-dev`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix anything.  Still getting all the same TS errors in VS2017

Comment: I think tracing the module resolution might help you track it down. If you add `"traceResolution": true` to `"compilerOptions"` you'll get a trace of how TS is determining what module to use. [This section of the TS documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#tracing-module-resolution), specifically the **Things to look out for** subsection, should help you make heads-or-tails of the output.

Comment: @YardGnomeNinja - hey, I think you just helped me over on the Aurelia Discourse forum -- are you tracking me (jk) :)  I added `traceResolution` as you suggested -- where do I see the output?  I don't see anything in the build output and I can't seem to run `tsc` from the command window.

Comment: I don't think this flag (`traceResolution`) is supported by MSBuild: https://apimirror.com/typescript/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.
So you can't use it in this case

Answer (score 15):

I fixed this by moving

```
"@types/node": "^10.11.6"
```

from `devDependencies` to the `peerDependencies` in my `package.json` file

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^10.11.6"
  },
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about the reasoning of moving it? Or a link explaining it?

Comment: Document is your friend:
https://nodejs.org/ru/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

Comment: @NordicShaw That documents what peer dependencies are. But why is that appropriate to use here? I've never seen a `@types/` package as a `peerDependency` before.

Answer (score 12):

For me, I fixed it by **change/add** "typeRoots" in compilerOptions (tsconfig.json)

```
"compilerOptions": {
        ....
         "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
        ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was `karma.config` file, which was causing the issues.

After I have deleted some of the types in the `package.json`, I managed to reduce the number of errors and there was only one - between `signalr` and `karma`.

[image: Screenshot of error]

For some reason I had a `.js`, not `.ts` karma config.
After I had switched to the [correct configuration](http://karma-runner.github.io/6.3/config/configuration-file.html) and restarted the VS, the problem was resolved.

It have needed some version of *node* as there was a `require` function used.
My theory is, Visual Studio automatically included types for accessible version of *node*, as a part of linting functionality for JavaScript.
But then, after it compiled typescript, another version of types for *node* was included - conflicting with the one already present.

None of the operations in `tsconfig.json` file would have resolved the issue, as the conflict was present between *node* types for TS and *node* types for JS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the packages *electron* and *node-opcua* were using different @types/node versions, resulting in the "*TS4090: (TS) Conflicting definitions for 'node*" error.

I had successfully fixed that error by providing manually a version for `@types/node` in my *peerDependencies* as pointed out in the error, however after installing the project elswhere this version changed and it turned out to be a bad idea. So I added `npm dedupe` as a `posinstall` script in my *package.json* and it works fine.
As [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-dedupe) states, it browses through the whole dependency tree and removes duplicated packages by moving them up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you import mongoose in 2 different files, make sure to use the same import eg. use

`const mongoose = require("mongoose");`

in both files

Answer (score 0):

Posting it in case it helps someone:

For me, the error was a human error.

I forgot to remove/comment out `typeRoots: []` within my `tsconfig.json`, so removing this line from the file fixed the issue for me

[image: tsconfig.json]

Answer (score -1):

Fixed that by

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```