# TS4090 Conflicting definitions for node

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I currently have two repos. One that acts as the angular front end and the other a nodejs back end. The two code bases are sharing some code so I am using `npm link` to give access. I'm currently writing another service that will use code from the nodejs backend. After exporting the function that has dependency on express, my front end code is now failing to build and now throwing the ts4090 error.

The only thing I've narrowed down to is that if I comment out that exported code it builds normally again. The only difference is that exported function is importing express for `NextFunction`.

The express-servce-static have conflicting versions now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolve 'Conflicting definitions for node' TS4090 error in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690600/resolve-conflicting-definitions-for-node-ts4090-error-in-vs-2017)

Comment: It does not. I think I have to some how `npm link` a separate module for my front end and one for my back end